# mount lan hdd into linux fedora

Tags: mount, hard-disk, cifs, lan

I'm really new in all of this, and I'm not really sure of how to do that, but I have an HDD connected to the LAN; from Windows, I run:

```
net use y: \\192.168.1.200\my-path\ condor /user:admin
```

I'm trying to do the same on Linux, "translating" the line above to work on my Fedora, but I'm not really sure on how to do it. I tried:

```
sudo mount //192.168.1.200/my-path/  -t cifs /mnt/y -o "username=admin"
```

but this doesn't work and I don't find anything about it because I'm not sure of what to search for to get the answer.

Comment: any error message?

Comment: You should check `dmesg` for any related messages. You might also get some clues if you use verbose `-v` option for `mount` (you can pass `-v` multiple times for more verbosity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install [Gigolo](https://www.maketecheasier.com/manage-remote-filesystems-with-gigolo/) and see what it returns. Gigolo is a graphical utility for the virtual filesystem GIO/GVfs which manages files over a TCP/IP network.

I think there's even a package for Fedora, in which case you can install it via

```
yum install gigolo
```

[Here's its manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gigolo).

Comment: If this answer solved your problem please consider accepting it.  In this way, the question will be marked as answered on the site, which will help other users looking for a solution.